# Switch in 3 Gang Hall Bath Does Nothing, Want to rewire to 2 gang with blank

Tags: wiring

Have three gang hall bath switch panel in which the first two control the fan and light; third does nothing.  Have tested all outlets and other lights; third switch seemingly inert yet wired to other two, with lone red wire.  Current tester across switch yields no current regardless of switch position.

Just want to lose third useless switch and replace with blank.  Anyone got easy solution?

Comment: Third wire may be for a light over sink.  And wire is in the wall

Comment: What do you mean by "current tester"? Can you post a photo of the inside of the box please?

Comment: it is unclear what your actual question is

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. We'll need more info before we can help you. Please [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know how better to contribute here.